# What is the difference between using $ in a mapped drive and not using it?

Tags: network-shares, mapped-drive

I have a script that maps shared drives from a couple of different servers when a user logs on. I recently changed some of the servers where the mappings went.

Now when the user logs on they are able to read from any of the mapped drives, but not write to them (so they cannot save or create new files). I made some additional changes to fix this and added the `$` to the mapping so before it looked like

> \\ServerName\ShareName

Now I have it like this:

> \\ServerName\C$\ShareName

What I'm trying to figure out is what the difference is? I can access the share either way, but only with the `$` can I write to the share.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $ implies a hidden share. If I wanted to create a share, but not allow someone who is browsing the network to see it, then I would append a $ to the end of the share name. Shared$  Windows by default shares each drive letter with a $, this is considered to be an 'Admin' share. So connecting to C$ means you are connecting to the root of drive C. From there you go to 'Sharename' to Read and Write your files. If you create the share and do it properly then you should be able to access 'Sharename' directly. Notice when you create the share, and name it, there is a permissions button . Hit that button and select full control. Select the security tab and add the group or user that you want to have access to the share then select the permissions that you want that group or user to have.

Comment: That was it. I had missed changing the permissions to `Full`. Everything else was correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Addressing the question of why one works while the other does not:

With the former, you are accessing the share called `ShareName`, with whatever permissions it was shared with (right click, properties, sharing tab). This share could map to any folder. It could be `C:\ShareName`. It could be `D:\ShareName`. It could be `C:\Users\Mike\MyFavouriteFolder`.

With the latter, you are accessing the share called `C$`, which maps to the root of the `C:\` drive. **If** the folder `C:\ShareName` happens to exist at that path, then `\\host\C$\ShareName` will access it - but as far as Windows is concerned, you are accessing the `C:\ShareName` folder via the `C$` administrative share, not the `ShareName` share.

As an aside, generally you should avoid using the administrative shares for a folder you actually intend to share. Those shares exist for ... administrative purposes. For example, if a company's domain admin needs to change a file on a client machine. When you actually want to share a specific folder, you should do so directly via the context menu.

Answer (score 1):

These shares are hidden administrative shares that administrators, programs, and services can use to manage the computer environment on the network.

These shares date from the [days of Windows 2000](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/bb727040%28v=technet.10%29) :

> Windows 2000 automatically shares folders for administrative purposes. These shares are appended with a dollar sign ($), which hides the shared folder from users who browse the computer. The root of each volume, the system root folder, and the location of the printer drivers are all hidden shared folders that you can gain access to across the network.
>
> **C$, D$, E$, and so on**
>
> The root of each volume on a hard disk is automatically shared, and the share name is the drive letter appended with a dollar sign ($). When you connect to this folder, you have access to the entire volume. You use the administrative shares to remotely connect to the computer to perform administrative tasks. Windows 2000 assigns the Full Control permission to the Administrators group.
>   Windows 2000 also automatically shares CD-ROM drives and creates the share name by appending the dollar sign to the CD-ROM drive letter.
>
> **Admin$**
>
> The system root folder, which is `C:\Winnt` by default, is shared as Admin$. Administrators can gain access to this shared folder to administer Windows 2000 without knowing in which folder it is installed. Only members of the Administrators group have access to this share. Windows 2000 assigns the Full Control permission to the Administrators group.
>
> **Print$**
>
> When you install the first shared printer, the `systemroot\System32\Spool\Drivers` folder is shared as Print$. This folder provides access to printer driver files for clients. Only members of the Administrators, Server Operators, and Print Operators groups have the Full Control permission. The Everyone group has the Read permission.

Since Windows 2000, the following shares has also been added :

- The FAX$ share
- The IPC$ share

For more information, see
[Wikipedia Administrative share](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share).